# Can you sacrifice Animate Dead AND the creature it enchants?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

My opponent has a creature with [Animate Dead](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Animate%20Dead) attached to it. I attacked him with [Emrakul, the Aeons Torn](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Emrakul%2C%20the%20Aeons%20Torn), forcing him to sacrifice 6 permanents to *Annihilator*. He wanted to sacrifice both Animate Dead and the creature it was enchanting. I said that was impossible, as sacrificing either one would cause the other to leave the battlefield. Which of us is right?

Comment: But don't worry, you're attacking with Emrakul. You're probably going to win anyway.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, if someone's asked to sacrifice multiple permanents, they can sacrifice Animate Dead *and* its enchanted creature.

As part of enacting Emrakul's Annihilator ability, your opponent has to to make six choices. These six choices are made all at once during resolution, and at that point they're all valid choices, and **then** after those choices are made, the ability dumps all six choices into the graveyard simultaneously.

Just about no triggered abilities can actually activate during effect resolution, so Animate Dead can't do its thing until that ability's fully resolved. Once it is, Animate Dead has left the battlefield and its triggered ability goes onto the stack:

> When Animate Dead leaves the battlefield, that creature's controller sacrifices it.

That creature's no longer around, and nothing happens.

Comment: The answer says that you must make six choices as the ability goes on the stack, but I think you make the choices when the ability resolves. Otherwise, nice answer!

Comment: You could still sacrifice both even if is asked you to sacrifice one at a time in order, because the game state isn't checked until the ability is fully resolved. It would be a different story say if Annihilator 1 triggered six individual times

Comment: @Rainbolt Thanks for pointing that out. [I've asked a question about that](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/27849/5573) - I don't doubt you but I'm interested in the rules behind it, plus it seems like a good question to have on-site.

Comment: @Aducci I'll add a note about that after I clarify the situation around Annihilator